# Support not where needed

Tags: support-structures

I got this model of a dragon off thingiverse and am printing it, but after it ran for a while, I realized that the there are multiple points that the print will try to print onto air since it did not put any support structure there, even though I selected "everywhere". My first questions is, why would it do this? and secondly, is there any way to remedy this?
I wanted to attach the picture of what it looks like, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: What slicer? What printer? What other settings did you use?

Comment: what is your support-angle?

Comment: to add a picture, you can just press the picture icon, then you drag-and-drop it there

Comment: Please post the thingiverse link so we can evaluate the source model on our own slicing software tools.

Comment: Oh, gees, I can't believe I forgot that information. I am using Cura on a Monoprice Maker Select. I used: .1mm Layer height, 1.2mm shell thickness, enabled retraction, 1.2

Comment: 1.2mm Bottom/Top thickness, 100% infill density, 40mm/s print speed, 210C temp with PLA, 60C bed temp, support type is everywhere, platform adhesion type is Brim. If I click on the ... button by Support type, I have lines as the structure type, 60 degrees Overhang angle for support, 15% fill amount, .7 X/Y distance, and .15mm Z distance. https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2830051

Comment: @ArthurWorst You can edit your original post to include all of the information directly into it. It's best to do it as comments can disappear after some time while your question, and the answers, will not.